# Put multiple objects in S3 in one request

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

Using aws-sdk for node.js how can I put several objects in one put request? There isn't anything in aws-sdk documentation that I can see? I'm also wondering how I can get multiple objects from an s3 bucket in one request. Unfortunately I can only list several objects at once. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. You can't even change the permissions on multiple objects in one request.